# TweetStream.track multiple keyword at once

Tags: ruby, twitter, tweetstream

I'm working with `TweetStream gem` in ruby and would like to know if there is a way to use

```
TweetStream::Client.new.track('key1', 'key2')
```

And track tweets with only **BOTH keywords** in them?
The normal use tracks Tweets with **either one** in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Twitter Stream Api docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track), you have to send a single search phrase (your 2 terms, separated by space):

```
TweetStream::Client.new.track('key1 key2')
```